# Tagging/Mentioning Friends in Comments via Graph Api

Tags: android, facebook, tagging

How could I mention friends in comment via Graph Api, as I know Open Graph
let us to tag ,if we  create some actions/objects or use already predefined actions.
My case is different , I would like to let users tag friends in a simple comment.They don't do anything related to an object or action and that is why I don't need to use Open Graph.
Please any solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First thing, without Open Graph you can forget the word **tag** using the graph API. You have to have use the OG for tagging.

Second thing, even by using OG you can **not** tag in a comment. When you publish a story using OG, you can tag frieds/places. But on comments, you can not tag anything using Graph API/OG.

Comment: Is it still like that? I mean still there is no update on Graph API to tag a friend by using Graph API? @Sahil Mittal